# How to navigate to FragmentB from FragmentA when button is clicked in FragmentA

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment for login, this has a button which when clicked should open register_fragment, Also in register their's button which when clicked should got to login_fragment from register_fragemnt.

Here's the code I tried.

```
public class Login_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container, false);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnLinkToRegister= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment register_frag =  new Register_fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity, register_frag);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }



}
```

Messages shown in Log Cat

```
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050044 type #0x12 is not valid
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.example.appointment_project.Register_fragment.onCreateView(Register_fragment.java:15)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-29 05:25:05.857: E/AndroidRuntime(897):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The login fragment is displayed but when I click the button which takes me to register fragment the activity crashes.
Please help me I am new to Android programming.

Edit-----
I have created an interface inside the Login_fragment.java which is implemented by MainActivity.java and the method is overrided inside the class but still my activity crashes

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SwitchFragments {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

           //add a fragment
           Login_fragment login_frag= new Login_fragment();
           fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_activity,login_frag,"Login Fragment");
           fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void switch_fragmen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Register_fragment register = new Register_fragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity,register);
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        }



}
```

LoginFragment.java

```
public class Login_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btnLinkToRegister;
    SwitchFragments switchFragments;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container, false);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        btnLinkToRegister= (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        switchFragments = (SwitchFragments) activity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switchFragments.switch_fragmen();

    }

    public interface SwitchFragments{
        public void switch_fragmen();
    }

}
```

What may be the issue ?

Comment: post the stack trace?

Comment: @AmitGupta: are you talking about the log cat messages ?

Comment: Yes, post the error log.

Comment: @AmitGupta: Please check the editted post.

Comment: what is the row - Register_fragment.java:15 ?

Comment: @Mayur see my updates. You need to initialize Button inside onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources$NotFoundException
```

It is b'coz you are accessing `Activity` layout from `Fragment`, and you can't access.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity, register_frag);
```

The problem it seems like you are managing `FragmentTransaction` through the Fragment class.
Its not a good way.

Better try to replace the `Fragment` from your `Activity` itself.

Edit:----------------------

```
public class Register_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    Button login;
    Communicate com;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        com = (Communicate) activity;
    }
    // Created an Interface
    interface Communicate{
        public void changeLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        login =// initiliza here
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        com.changeLayout();

    }


}
```

And implement this interface in your MainActivity.

then

```
@Override
    public void changeLayout() {
            Register_fragment register_frag =  new Register_fragment();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity, register_frag);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
    }
```

**Required Fix:**

**Try initializing in `onCreateView`**

```
@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment,container, false);
  btnLinkToRegister = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
  btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
  return view;
 }
```

Comment: How can I navigate from the login fragment to register fragment ?

Comment: you mean, you want switch between fragments or activity when clicking button?

Comment: Switch between fragments. FragmentA -> FragmentB and vice-versa.

Comment: okey check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176999/how-to-switch-between-fragments-during-onclick?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_activity,
                        new RegisterFragment(), "registerFragment")
                        .addToBackStack("register").commit();
```