# Transaction between Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` and an `activity`.there are some fields and an `button` in `fragment`.When i click an `button in fragment` then i want to go to an `activity`.In that activity i have another `button`.when i click on that button i want to return from the present `activity` to the previous `fragment`.Every thing works fine.what i need is i want to `recreate the fragment` when i `return to the fragment from the activity`..i.e,for example in the `fragment` if i enter anything in the `edit_text` before passing to the `activity`, which is also presented when i `returned from the activity`.(the `fragment` is same as how i left from `fragment`) which is i don't want .i want a fresh page.i want to `recreate a fragment` when i returned from activity ..i need to select fields newly..can any one suggest any help..thanks in advance..

Comment: navigating from fragment to activity is difficult, i guess

Comment: You can use onActivityResult and pass intent with bundle from the second activity to the first which manage the fragments. Then from there you can update them

Comment: @Exceptional we can navigate the fragment to activity via intent..

Comment: the fragment is in same activity or in different activity ?

Comment: @Yume117 thanks for the replay..i  previously did as you said using onActivityResult in one of my app..but the scenario in here is different.

Comment: Can you explain more about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use main FragmentActivity and Fragments and organize transactions between fragments. I didn't meet examples with Activity and Fragment in one Addlication.