# How to go one Fragment to another when I will click on TextView Id?

Tags: java, android

How to go one `Fragment` to another when I will click on `TextView` Id?

**Error shows:**

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tripigator.Overview cannot be cast to android.app.Activity.`

and error comes from these lines :

```
TextView overview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_overview);
            overview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProjectOverview.this, Overview.class);
                    startActivity(intent);              
                }
            });
```

So please anybody help me how to move from one `fragment` to another by clicking text item.

**ProjectOverview class :**

```
public class ProjectOverview extends FragmentActivity {     
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project_overview);
         initialingpaging();             
        TextView overview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_overview);
        overview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProjectOverview.this, Overview.class);
                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });
    }

     private void initialingpaging() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Overview.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Highlight.class.getName()));               
            mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);            
            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);     

        }
}
```

**Two Fragment Classes:**

```
public class Overview extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {    
        if(container == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview,container,false);
    }
}


public class Highlight extends Fragment {       
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {              
        if(container == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.highlight,container,false);
    }
}
```

**Layout Interface:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/project_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"          
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_overview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Overview" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_highlite"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Highlight" />
        </LinearLayout>      
    </RelativeLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Overview is Fragment not a activity so you can not to start using start activity.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I know Overview is Fragment not a Activity. But I dont know what code I ll write please send me code to move one Fragment to another according to above code. Please helpme.

Comment: @Alam where is the view pager in XML design.

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176999/how-to-switch-between-fragments-during-onclick

Comment: and this too http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

Answer (score 0):

you should not use intent in fragment to move another fragment

**and check this for whole example** http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/
use this.

```
((yourfragmentActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(1,//desired activity 0=first 1= second and so on
                        true);
```

insted

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ProjectOverview.this, Overview.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @M S Gadag Please send me full code to move one Fragment to another according to above code. please

Answer (score 0):

You can't initiate the fragment using Intent.Try this it helps.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
FragmentManager frgManager;
FragmentTransaction ft;

fragment = new Overview();
ft = frgManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_content, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

If you use View-Pager

```
your_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)
```