# recyclerview open activity with navbar on click item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new android developper. In my application I have a main activity with toolbar, that contains a title, and a recycler view.

The recycler view contains some items. I want to open a activity on click on them. My code is able to open the activity but the toolbar disappear.

I open the activity like this:

```
public VHolder(final View itemView){
        super(itemView);

        title = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle));

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", currentNews.title);
                intent.putExtra("content", currentNews.htmlContent);
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Have you any ideas and advices ?

Sorry about my poor english ;).

Comment: show the code of ArticleActivity

Comment: I am guessing your new activity doesn't simply have a toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of my problem of toolbar. The opened activity (ArticleActivity) not extends "AppCompatActivity" like the main activity but, "Activity".

Answer (score 3):

You are doing everything in the correct way. The problem is that toolbar is just another widget on your `Activity` and cannot be shared between multiple activities. So you should add toolbar view to the layout of the `Activity` which you are starting (ArticleActivity).

As another option you can show `Fragment` over RecyclerView instead of starting new `Activity`. Similar to this: [how to open a different fragment on recyclerview OnClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984879/how-to-open-a-different-fragment-on-recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten a detail. In design mode, I see the toolbar in the opened activity (ArticleActivity). It define into the theme of the application.