# Opening another fragment on RecyclerView item click doesn't hide RecylerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This uses `RecyclerView`, `NavigationBar` and 2 fragments(Home and Bookmark).
`Home_fragment.xml` implements RecyclerView and has 1 `FrameLayout` to be used as a Layout Container when opening new fragment(Bookmark Fragment).
I am using an interface to handle clicks on items.

The problem is when opening new fragment on RecyclerView item click, the fragment opens but remains behind the RecyclerView.

I used `recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)` inside OnClick method, it works, but i think it hides the RecyclerView permanently, it shows a blank layout when navigating back from Bookmark to Home.
To make it visivle when navigating back, i included `recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in OnBackPressed which is in `Main_Activity.java`, but it abruptly stops the application if i click the back button.

I checked this [Fragment doesn't replace and hide another fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470754/fragment-doesnt-replace-and-hide-another-fragment), but using the suggested solution didn't make any difference.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements MyAdapter.OnNoteListener {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
MyAdapter myAdapter;
LinkedList<Data_Items> data_items = new LinkedList<Data_Items>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    data_items.add(new Data_Items(R.drawable.a, "Pink", "This is a pink color"));
    // + a few more items         

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(data_items, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
@Override
public void onNoteClick(int position) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_container, new BookmarkFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}}
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment"
android:id="@+id/frag">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

More details:
I have asked a different question related to this project.
[Fragment won't open on RecyclerView item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049572/fragment-wont-open-on-recyclerview-item-click)

what is i need to do to make it work?

Comment: Just change your FrameLayout elevation ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int)

Comment: put your new fragment code please.

Comment: @majidghafouri Check the other question i have asked, it includes all the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049572/fragment-wont-open-on-recyclerview-item-click

Comment: @AnasMehar I put it in OnNoteClick method, but it didn't do anything. The new fragment still opens behind RecyclerView

Comment: @Traveller9211 Then set recyclerview elevation -1 and framelayout 2

Comment: @AnasMehar The RecyclerView is still there in the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i got it working-

- `activity_main.xml` should contain the `layout_container (FrameLayout)`. Nothing else.
- `HomeFragment.xml` should contain the `RecyclerView` and `Navigation drawer`
- Main_activity.java should have the code to replace the `layout_container` with 
  HomeFragment Just put the code there no need of any listener.
- In `HomeFragment.java` we can set the listener on RecyclerView items to open the other 
  Fragments/Activities.