# How to pass button clicks from a Fragment to Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to access a button named `verify_otp` in my GetPhone fragment through the MainActivity.

I've tried using 
`btnVerify = findViewById(R.id.verify_otp)`, but this creates a NullPointerException.

I've also uses an interface that handles button click as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176999/how-to-switch-between-fragments-during-onclick) , again creates a NullPointerException.

I've also tried using a function to return my button like this

```
public ImageButton getMyButton(){
return myButton;
}
```

calling this in my main activity:

```
GetPhone getPhoneFragment = new GetPhone();
ImageButton btnVerify = getPhoneFragment.getMyButton();
```

This also produces a NullPointerException.

Here is my GetPhone fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".GetPhone"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#fff"
android:outlineProvider="bounds">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_left_curved"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_dropdown" />

</RelativeLayout>


   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
       android:id="@+id/phone_num"
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
       android:background="@drawable/get_phone_center"
       android:paddingStart="16dp"
       android:paddingEnd="16dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:inputType="phone"
       android:hint="@string/enter_phone_number" />

   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/verify_otp"
       android:textColor="#fff"
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:background="@drawable/button_next"
       android:src="@drawable/icon_right"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I initialize my phone fragment in my Activity:

```
 private void initPhoneFragment(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        GetPhone fragment = new GetPhone();
        // Pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Fragments via buttonClick in firstFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563583/replace-fragments-via-buttonclick-in-firstfragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the button belongs to the fragment, it should be the fragment the one who handles the button click, not the activity.

In your GetPhone java code, do this:

```
View btnVerify; //global variable

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.get_phone, container, false); //put the proper layout xml file name
    btnVerify = view.findViewById(R.id.verify_otp);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnVerify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = activityContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = new OTP();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

If you want to handle the replacing of fragments in the activity, then you can create an interface between the fragment and the activity and do the callback in the onClick method instead of making the transaction directly.

More information: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this gives me a null pointer exception. I did put this code after loading the GetPhone fragment.

Comment: Please check my modified answer

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. I had this false notion that since the fragment is a totally different file, it might not be directly possible to pass functions from a fragment that can affect the functions in its parent activity. A new thing learned today as well!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this** , on button click

```
  OTP fragment = new OTP(); //OTP fragment
  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, the button is in a fragment. Accessing the button via my Activity is generating a NullPointerException.

Comment: Are you trying to access button in fragment through activity?